# Create Grafana dashboard from Allure report results/appium test automation

Tags: appium, grafana, appium-android, appium-ios, allure

I am trying to create a Grafana dashboard for my mobile automation project and need some heads up on how to proceed. Searching on Google hasn't helped much. We export the results for our mobile automation to allure reports and now want to create send the results to a dashboard. Is there any API to send allure results to Grafana? or should I export my appium test results to a DB and then send it to Grafana, if yes, then any way ahead? New to dashboarding stuff so need help

Answer (score 0):

Allure generates influxdb (and prometheus) files in export directory. You need to feed this file to influxDB database. After that you set Grafana to pull from that database and show data.